# How to change desktop password?

Tags: gnome

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I can not change my desktop password. Can somebody help me on how to change the desktop password?

Answer (score 1):

To change the password of a user account in Ubuntu use the following way

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Then type in the terminal

```
   sudo passwd user-name
```

It will ask for new password like:

```
Enter new UNIX password:
```

Enter the new password and confirm it then your good to go.

**EDIT 1.**

To know the user-name (I believe you know that) you are using type the command in the Terminal

```
whoami
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to use the Unity-GUI, go to "System Settings" and then to "User" in the left lower corner. Now you must choose the user and after that simply click on the field right of "Password". Now enter your old password and your new password.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to a console or open a terminal and type in `passwd`
if you are using keys you might need to run the `seahorse` command
to update those. If you forgot your password you might be able
to recover it by selecting “[recovery mode](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/reset-your-forgotten-ubuntu-password-in-2-minutes-or-less/)” booting into single
user mode and dropping into root shell.